# Multiview controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

I wrote the following code for multiview where I am using gridview and datalist:

```
<ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
    <div class="alert alert-success" >
      <div class="divbtn" style="text-align:right">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="gridbtn" runat="server" CssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-th" OnClick="gridbtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="listbtn" runat="server" CssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" OnClick="listbtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
      </div>
    </div>

    <asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="multiview" ActiveViewIndex="0"> 
        <asp:View runat="server" ID="gridview">   
             <uc1:GridControl runat="server" ID="GridControl"/>
        </asp:View>

        <asp:View runat="server" ID="listview">
            <uc1:Listing runat="server" ID="Listing" />
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>

</asp:Content>
```

I am using two link buttons to call their respective views by firing two separate events as follows.

```
protected void listbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        multiview.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }

    protected void gridbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        multiview.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
```

Suppose, my datalist (Index=1) is active on my page and if there is a post back it should still be showing the datalist but on postback it automatically switches back to grid view (Index=0). I really need help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the index to a session variable and then read it back on post back like this:

To save:

```
Session["index"] = index.ToString();
```

Read it on page load like this:

```
Index = Session["index"];
```

You will need the session variable to maintain state per user session. If you want to maintain state for the application then you have to use the application variable.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. I used the session variable and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hi add the following code in your page_load event.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    multiview.ActiveViewIndex=0;
}
```

Comment: I did this earlier but had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are setting the multiview's active index to zero on every post back like follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 multiview.ActiveViewIndex=0;
}
```

this will cause the multiview to set active index as 0 on every post back.To avoid this you have to set it as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    multiview.ActiveViewIndex=0;
}
}
```

Comment: can you copy your code in page load event here..are you calling any other methods in the page load event?check carefully if you are setting multiview's index as zero in any methods which is called in page load event.

Comment: Actually, the problem was with the post back. With every post back, default values were loaded. So I used the session variable to save the index and I loaded it every time the page load happened and it worked !!